# How can I print the msg_true in case of true?

Tags: if-statement, lua

I want to write code like `msg = result ? msg_v : msg_x` in Lua.
I tried to do something like:

```
result = true
msg_v = "true!"
msg_x = "false!"

msg = (msg_v and result) or msg_x
print(msg)
```

but I get `true` as result and not `true!`. how can I fix that?

Comment: Why did you move `result` behind?

Comment: @shingo what do you mean ?

Comment: I mean you should put `result` ahead: `result and msg_v or msg_x`

Comment: @shingo Why does it matter?

Comment: Of course the order matters, currently your expression is equivalent to `msg_v ? result : msg_x`.

Comment: `and` in Lua is lazy-evaluation operator, so the order of operands matters

Answer (score 0):

Check out my Version (colored)

```
€ lua
Lua 5.4.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2022 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> msg_v, msg_x = "true!", "false!"
> result = true
> msg = not result and ('\27[1;31m%s: %s\27[m'):format(type(result),msg_x) or ('\27[1;32m%s: %s\27[m'):format(type(result),msg_v)
> print(msg)
boolean: true!
> result = false
> msg = not result and ('\27[1;31m%s: %s\27[m'):format(type(result),msg_x) or ('\27[1;32m%s: %s\27[m'):format(type(result),msg_v)
> print(msg)
boolean: false!
>
```

Impression
[image: Lua 5.4 Standalone (REPL)]
Formating False in blinking red Capital Letters do...

```
msg = not result and ('\27[1;5;31m%s: %s\27[m'):format(type(result):upper(), msg_x:upper()) or ('\27[1;32m%s: %s\27[m'):format(type(result), msg_v)
```

...have fun ;-)

PS: Check out the special (datatype) Cases and learn how to catch them

```
> result = "I am a String"
> msg = not result and ('\27[1;5;31m%s: %s\27[m'):format(type(result):upper(), msg_x:upper()) or ('\27[1;32m%s: %s\27[m'):format(type(result), msg_v)
> print(msg)
string: true!
> result = {"I am a String in a Table"}
> msg = not result and ('\27[1;5;31m%s: %s\27[m'):format(type(result):upper(), msg_x:upper()) or ('\27[1;32m%s: %s\27[m'):format(type(result), msg_v)
> print(msg)
table: true!
> result = print -- Just a Function
> msg = not result and ('\27[1;5;31m%s: %s\27[m'):format(type(result):upper(), msg_x:upper()) or ('\27[1;32m%s: %s\27[m'):format(type(result), msg_v)
> print(msg)
function: true!
> result = io.stdin -- User Data
> msg = not result and ('\27[1;5;31m%s: %s\27[m'):format(type(result):upper(), msg_x:upper()) or ('\27[1;32m%s: %s\27[m'):format(type(result), msg_v)
> print(msg)
userdata: true!
```

...and...

```
> result = math.deg(math.pi)
> msg = not result and ('\27[1;5;31m%s: %s\27[m'):format(type(result):upper(), msg_x:upper()) or ('\27[1;32m%s: %s\27[m'):format(type(result), msg_v)
> print(msg)
number: true!
```

...in the meantime you are fine with `not` if `result`...

```
> result = nil
> msg = not result and ('\27[1;5;31m%s: %s\27[m'):format(type(result):upper(), msg_x:upper()) or ('\27[1;32m%s: %s\27[m'):format(type(result), msg_v)
> print(msg)
NIL: FALSE!
```

...simply not exists.